# Using SELECT SUM WHERE in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum, where-clause

I am learning PHP with MySQL and trying to use SELECT SUM to give me a total from column 'QuantityChecked', but only WHERE the 'Lot' matches and then display it. In this case I have provided some of the code I am using, please let me know if I further need to define this question or the code. The issue I am having at this point is the 'Lot' does not seem to be getting carried over from qcapproval.php into qcapproval-exec.php which I am gathering from the following error message

*Undefined index: Lot in qcapproval-exec.php*

Code below.

qcapproval.php

```
<form action="qcapproval-exec.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; echo $row['Lot']; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Lot" value="<?php echo $row['Lot']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="CheckedBy" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['CheckedBy']; ?>" />
```

qcapproval-exec.php

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('there was a problem connecting to the database' . mysql_error());
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$QuantityChecked= $_POST['QuantityChecked'];
$AnodThickness= $_POST['AnodThickness'];
$QtyPassed= $_POST['QtyPassed'];
$QtyFailed= $_POST['QtyFailed'];
$SealsChecked= $_POST['SealsChecked'];
$SealsPassed= $_POST['SealsPassed'];
$SealsFailed= $_POST['SealsFailed'];
$GraphicsChecked= $_POST['GraphicsChecked'];
$GraphicsPassed= $_POST['GraphicsPassed'];
$GraphicsFailed= $_POST['GraphicsFailed'];
$CheckedBy= $_POST['CheckedBy'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$Lot = $_GET['Lot'];
// OR
// $id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "UPDATE logs SET  QuantityChecked= '$QuantityChecked',
                         AnodThickness = '$AnodThickness',
                         QtyPassed = '$QtyPassed',
                         QtyFailed = '$QtyFailed', 
                         SealsChecked = '$SealsChecked',
                         SealsPassed = '$SealsPassed',
                         SealsFailed = '$SealsFailed',
                         GraphicsChecked = '$GraphicsChecked',
                         GraphicsPassed = '$GraphicsPassed', 
                         GraphicsFailed = '$GraphicsFailed',
                         CheckedBy = '$CheckedBy',
                         DateTimeChecked = now() 
                         WHERE id = $id ";
$conn->query($sql);

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(QuantityChecked) AS TotalQuantityChecked FROM logs WHERE Lot = $Lot");
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum= $row['TotalQuantityChecked'];
$conn->close();
}

echo $sum;
echo "Record Updated.";
```

I have made an edit to reflect the new code and changes to this question

Comment: Hm, lots wrong. Where to begin...

Comment: Strawberry, would you mind elaborating? I am trying to learn.

Comment: `$verify_Qty;`??? `'$verify_Qty'` <- not valid concatenation. Nor is this: `Lot='$Lot'`. Why would you use `$conn->query()` on the returned `mysqli_result` object? You should read a tutorial. [These are the docs on the `$result` object you'll be working with.](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) Also beware of SQL injection. Use PDO. I'm going crazy man.

Comment: fix what he says, execute the command and then also post the ERROR you are getting. never forget to post the errors.

Comment: Sjagr and Abel, thanks for the input. I have gone ahead and modified my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're submitting the form using `POST` so the values of hidden elements would be in `$_POST`, not `$_GET`.

```
$Lot = $_POST['Lot'];
```